# Summation involving floor function with powers

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I want to perform $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k  \lfloor\frac{N}{2^i}\rfloor7^{i-1} $ where $N$ is an even integer.

Is there any technique which performs it?

THanks.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, the edit does not make much sense since the powers of $2's$ cancel to give $\lfloor N/2 \rfloor$. Can the OP please clarify? Thanks.

Comment: Note that the powers of 2 almost cancel out against each other.

Comment: What is $N$? Integer, real? If $N$ is an integer, it is helpful to write $N = 2^ab$ with $b$ odd.

Comment: Yea N is an even integer!